# Chaining cucumber scenarios

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am trying to understand how I can group scenarios together logically. Lets say I have a Feature such as viewing cart after filling an order.

```
Given I am on the items page
When I click shop button
And I add an apple 
And I add a bananna
When I click next
Then I should see my cart summary
```

Now I want to go futher.. such as removing some items. I dont want to make a whole new feature file. I just want to create a new scenario that referances this one above. How can I add another scenario that just starts where this one left off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is [background](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background):

> Background allows you to add some context to the scenarios in a single feature. A Background is much like a scenario containing a number of steps. The difference is when it is run. The background is run before each of your scenarios but after any of your Before Hooks.

Using this idea, you could do something like:

```
Feature: Shopping cart testing

  Background:
    Given I am on the items page
    When I click shop button
    And I add an apple 
    And I add a bananna
    And I click next

  Scenario: Check shopping cart is present
    Then I should see my cart summary

  Scenario: I should be able to remove an item
    When I remove an item
    Then the shopping cart should have one item
```

Note that both scenarios are independent though they share a common background (a set of initial steps).

I usually use Background's in my tests though I only use Givens. From my point of view, a background should present a state and not actions performed by the user (though this is just my opinion). I know that there are tests out there using `when` in backgrounds and it's an allowed practice.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so in this example the background would get ran twice?

Comment: Yes, it would be run once per scenario.

Comment: Hmm I was hoping more so something like Scenario A, then the next one would start like Given Scenario A, more things. I am trying to avoid a complete restart like background would do but rather once scenario A is done, scenario B picks up on the same page that scenario A left off.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a scenario that tests different things (functionalities) in it. It should be separated in different scenarios and each of them should test only one thing (even though the steps are repeated in order to get to that state). One test should test one thing only

Comment: @acontell super! what if I want to write I add an apple, I add an orange, as the steps, how do I avoid repetition there. Look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250093/cucumber-data-driven-testing-multiple-similar-steps-in-same-scenario